# jQuery Pagination plugin go to page on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

On my search page I'm using bootstrap with jQuery Pagination plugin (http://josecebe.github.io/twbs-pagination) to add pagination. So far the pagination looks fine and seems to work visually, but I'm struggling with getting it to go to the correct page when clicking it.

This is what I have:

```js
    $('#pagination-demo').twbsPagination({
        totalPages: <?= $searchResults['pages'];?>,
        visiblePages: 7,
        startPage: <?= $page;?>,
        first: '&laquo;&laquo;',
        next: '&raquo;',
        prev: '&laquo;',
        last: '&raquo;&raquo;',
        onPageClick: function (event, page) {
            window.open("/search.php?term=<?= $searchTerm;?>&page=" + page, "_self");
        }
    });
```

I thought by doing this it would go to the link when I clicked the page, but at the moment it just keeps looping the same URL without doing anything.

Where am I going wrong? I am not super familiar with javascript so apologies if this is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Needed to add `initiateStartPageClick: false`